# reading in file and parsing the input

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

So I have a file in which the first 3 lines will always refer to "states" and the remainder will refer to "transitions" I know the first 3 lines will always be in the same format, and tabs between inputs on the same line, but the number of "transitions" is unknown, but will always start on line 4.

So I handled the "states" by

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    myFile >> junk;
    myFile >> stateNum;
    myFile >> designation;
    //make object and put in container
}
```

And now I need to handle the "transitions", so if my input file looks like

```
state 1 a
state 2 b
state 3 c
trans a b c d &
trans d s i & 3
...
trans 4 e & d g
```

where all the whitespace on the same line is a tab, state/trans go into `junk` because they're not needed since I know 1-3 is state and the remainder is transition. how do I now start from the **beginning of line 4** and continue til the end of the file? Basically, what `if` condition do I use to make this work

```
if(???){
    myFile >> junk;
    myFile >> one;
    myFile >> two;
    ...
    myFile >> five;
    //create object and place in container
}
```

where one, two,.. five are declared earlier and one,..., five correspond to the 5 entries after "trans"

Comment: What about reading line by line into a line string (getline) and parse arguments with istringstream (using the current line string)?

Comment: And if the syntax of your input lines is indeed as shown, `trans` is *not* "junk". A line *not* starting with it cannot be a transition and the loop reading transitions should terminate.

Comment: @WhozCraig the input is very controlled, there will be no errors in the text file. if this was production code or something I would totally agree, but I know that the format will always be correct in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try placing

```
myFile >> junk;
myFile >> stateNum;
myFile >> designation;
```

before the loop and then reading each transition inside a loop, a while loop since you don't know how many there'll be.

Comment: well I need to loop with junk, stateNum, and designation to go around 3 times, so I could write it out 9 times but its nice to have it in a loop, especially since inside the loop I have 3 `if` statements depending on the designation

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't read your question closely enough - that for loop kind of makes sense then (but using getline three times and parsing the line would be neater).  Once the loop for the three state lines is done you'll need a while loop for the transitions.

Answer (score 0):

As Dieter said, you should use a stringstream and getline

```
string line;

while (getline (myFile, line)){
//this will loop until the end of the file
  stringstream line_stream(line); 
  string word; 
  while (line >> word){
  //this will loop until there are words (transitions) on the line)
  //(your code)
}
```